# Removing outlier in data for NN, good or bad idea?

Tags: python, neural-network, outliers

I have some data that has some outliers. My data however has a direction to it and has trends that i need to consider when looking for outlier. What an outlier is however, is not simply a yes or no answer. The only thing i can say is that the farther away a data point is from the trend, the more likely it is, that it is an outlier i would like to not include in my data.

Given things like stand deviation, linear regressions, and the chunk of data i am looking at all depend on context, there is no static function i know of to determine if something is an outlier or not.

I can select good outliers using various techniques but the problem is, anytime you get rid of outliers, you are using context of the data you are picking the outlier from.

I know that when you prepare your data for a NN, data has to always be prepared the exact same way. That is, it goes through a set of static processes/functions. The techniques used to select outliers, require context, and context changes, so the function changes. I am not sure if the differences in how an outlier is selected, is enough to throw of the integrity of the model.

If this is true, are there any good static methods to select an outlier?

Answer (score 0):

A model-independent way of selecting outliers is based upon the distribution of errors.  This boils down to:

1. Fit the model with all data points
2. Calculate the residual error for each data point
3. Eliminate outliers based on some threshold
4. Re-fit the model from scratch with outliers removed
5. (Optionally repeat until a termination condition is met, e.g. no outliers are removed)

The threshold of elimination is problem- and metric-dependent.  One approach to outlier elimination is computing a z-score on the residual errors (subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation of the residual errors) and then removing any points with an absolute value greater than a defined threshold (which equates to number of standard deviations from the mean at which points are identified as outliers).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score

This is a general, model-independent approach that assumes residuals are normally-distributed (or at least that outliers can be reasonably identified based on relative error).

If you have other assumptions regarding the distribution of the residual, you can apply other probabilistic criteria (e.g. fit a distribution on the residual errors, then apply a probabilistic threshold for each point).  This is more involved though, and if you don't have any belief a priori about the characteristics of the residual error distribution (other than "large errors are likely outliers") then z-score is the way to go.

The foregoing discusses *how* to identify outliers, but doesn't address *whether you should*.  This is an application-dependent question.  If outliers are not informative of behavior you want to model, then they can be removed from training.  However, if you want your model to predict average (or other metric-optimizing) behavior inclusive of outliers, then they should be retained.